# Instantiate a *game scene* view Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So, I am trying to instantiate a view controller. The issue is, that the view that I am trying *to* instantiate is a gameScene view controller (Sprite Kit). Also, the view that I am instituting *from* is also a gameScene view. If I were instantiating from a normal UIViewController, I would do this:

```
let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("main")
self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)
//the view that I am instantiating's class name is "GameScene"
```

When I try to run this, I get two errors:

```
gameScene does not have member named "storyboard"
'GameScene' does not have a member named 'showViewController'
```

Can anybody please explain why this does not work, and also please post a working solution?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Could you post some more of your code? Which lines were causing the errors above?

Comment: the two lines above. the vc... stuff

Answer (score 0):

This is because the game scene does not have a property called `storyboard` or `showViewController`. These are part of the `UIViewController` class. 
. To access them inside `GameScene` you can create a property inside the GameScene pointing to the current `UIViewController`.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var gameViewController : UIViewController!
}
```

You can assign the property inside the `GameViewController` class.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {

        // Configure the view code

        scene.gameViewController = self // Added line

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Then you can use it inside `GameScene` like this.

```
let vc : AnyObject! = self.gameViewController.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("main")
self.gameViewController.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)
```