# Swift MKMapView returning nil in GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, mapkit, mkmapview

I'm currently experimenting with MapKit and SpriteKit, however I have run into a problem.

When I try to convert map coordinates to a point on my screen (in my GameScene), I get an error: `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`

The following code produces the error and is in a function that (for testing purposes) runs when the screen is tapped.
`monster.position = (mapView?.convert(spawnLocation, toPointTo: view))!`

`monster` is an SKSpriteNode declared at the top of my GameScene. `spawnLocation` is just a set of coordinates (I checked and they should be visible on the screen). `mapView` is declared at the top of my GameScene like so: `var mapView = GameViewController().map` (I believe my problem is here)

Checking if `mapView` contains a value or not results in nothing being printed to the console:

```
if (mapView != nil) {
        print("not nil")
        monster.position = (mapView?.convert(spawnLocation, toPointTo: view))!
}
```

My map shows up when I run the app, however nothing happens when the above code is executed. I think my problem is with the way I am currently accessing the map from the GameViewController, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

To clarify: my map is declared in my GameViewController and I need to access it from my GameScene so that I can convert the coordinates to a point in the view.

NOTE: I may just be using the convert function wrong.

GameViewController:

```
@IBOutlet var parentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet var skview: SKView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    map.delegate = self
    map.showsScale = false
    map.showsPointsOfInterest = false
    map.showsUserLocation = true
    map.showsBuildings = true
    map.isZoomEnabled = false
    map.isScrollEnabled = false
    map.isPitchEnabled = false
    map.isRotateEnabled = false

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance((locationManager.location?.coordinate)!, 400, 400)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: false)

    parentView.addSubview(map)
    parentView.addSubview(skview)

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after continuing to work on my issue, I took another look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228212/instantiate-a-game-scene-view-swift) question (I had already tried the solution in the answer - it didn't work).
I noticed that my problem might be that the scene in which I was trying to access the `MKMapView`/`GameViewController` from wasn't the first scene.
When I added the following to my code, it printed nil:

```
print("view controller", self.gameViewController)
```

I then looked at the code responsible for transitioning from the first scene to the one I was having issues with, and I added a line:

```
let signedInTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)

let nextScene = GameScene(size: scene!.size)
nextScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

nextScene.gameViewController = self.gameViewController /* ADDED THIS LINE */

scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: signedInTransition)
```

Turns out my problem was that my scene didn't actually have a `GameViewController` and therefore

```
let gameViewController:GameViewController!
```

never actually contained a value.

Comment: did this worked adding current context or current controller object and handling it in other controller I did same but didn't worked for me earlier

Comment: @iOSGeek I am not entirely sure what you are asking...what I described above did work for me. If it does not work for you, provide some more detail about what exactly your issue is